# How to increase ksoftirqd usage for testing

Tags: cpu

I have developed an application to calculate the percentage of ksoftirqd usage per CPU core and I want to test this. I am flagging an alarm if the usage is more than 50%.

To test this, I need to load the system in such a way that it increases the "ksoftirqd" usage drastically.

Are there scripts/tools available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to increase Ksoftirqs. I am doing syn flood ([link](https://www.binarytides.com/python-syn-flood-program-raw-sockets-linux/)) which is increasing the the load on ksoftirqs.
Thank you

The program was written in python2 but can be converted to python3 easily.

Comment: Since (your) question was "Are there scripts/tools available to do this?" perhaps an example or two would be helpful here?

Comment: Thanks jeff. added the link to the program that i used to bump up soft interrupts.